# Is there any way to make PHP load classes verbosely, indicating the full path to the .php file?

Tags: php, debugging

I would like to make PHP print out debugging information, including the full path to the .php file, to standard error whenever it loads a class: e.g.

Loaded MyClass from /path/to/my/class/MyClass.php

is there any way to do this without knowing in advance where the source files are?

[edited to clarify that I really care about the full path to the .php file, and that I don't know in advance where the source files are]

Comment: Yes.  The 'how' depends on where you want it to go.  Options include from logging into a log file, sending that information back through FirePHP or storing it all to display on a web document somewhere.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP does not have static constructors, you cannot automagically do something when a class is loaded. Your best bet is probably to print the message after the class definition (or use `__autoload` as Josh instructed, but that might require some reworking on your end).

```php
class Foo
{
    /* stuff */
}

echo "Class Foo loaded from " . __FILE__ . "\n";
```

**EDIT** Sorry to say, but PHP provides absolutely *no hook* to when a class is loaded or first instantiated, even in the [dirtiest corners of its weird extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php). You will not be able to get away without either editing the classes' source files (and use my solution) or organize them in a conventional hierarchy to put them in (and use Josh's solution).

There is [feature request #48546](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48546) that asks for a way to set a callback to when a file will be included but it's not going anywhere. Otherwise, people seem content with `__autoload`.

At best, you may call `get_declared_classes` at any time and see what's already been loaded.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about the `__FILE__` which I had totally forgotten about :)

Comment: Thanks @zneak, but I'm really looking for a solution that doesn't require me to know in advance where the source files are (or have write access to them).  The original question was ambiguous about this, so I've clarified again.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for -- thanks!  Shame it's a negative one, but that's PHP I guess :)

Comment: @dnw, I don't like posting negative answers too. If you think that solved your problem, though, consider clicking the checkmark below the  score of this answer; it tells your question was answered.

Comment: @zneak:  Done.  Thx.  I'm a newbie here :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [__autoload($class)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    echo "Loading: $class_name";
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

To do this, you just skip your explicit imports, like "include x.php" or "require_once x.php", and the autoloader finds it for you.

Comment: I want to show the full path to the .php file.  Sorry if this wasn't clear enough in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a message into the constructor function for each class that will output some sort of debugging message like this (though I am going to have to see if it is possible to find the exact document that the source is in and add it in if I find it) but this should give you an idea:

```
<?php

    class something()
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo "New instance of class:something is being made.";
            echo "Class is loaded from ".realpath(__FILE__);
        }
    }

    $var=new something();

?>
```

Output:

```
New instance of class:something is being made.
Class is loaded from /var/www/someFolder/incs/myclasses.php
```

Edit: Above change will echo out the message when you create a new object of the class like `$var= new something();` it won't kick in at any point prior to that though.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not executed _when_ PHP loads a class.

Comment: @zneak Ahhh, okay, I understood *loads* to mean when a class is instancted, not when the file is included.

Comment: I really want to see the path to the .php file

Comment: Thanks, @Fluffeh.  I now realize how misleading my original question was.  I don't know in advance where the source files are (they could be a third party library, for example).  I've updated the question accordingly.